# ignore Mouseout event from child element of Mouseover element

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseover, event-bubbling, dom-events

I need to display a tooltip for an image on mouseover.  I wrote the following code for that.  My current issue is that when I put the image into the tooltip div, the event occurs only for the image element.  How can I ignore the mouseover and mouseout event from child element of my parent tooltip div?

```
$("document").ready(function() {
        $('.tooltip').mouseover(function(e){
            var id = $(this).siblings('.tooltip-c').attr('id');
            $('.tp'+id).fadeIn(500);
            $('.tp'+id ).mouseout(function(event){
                $('.tp'+id).fadeOut(300);
            });
        });
    });
```

Please help-out me guys.  I'm helpless.

Comment: how to ignore Mouseout event from child element of Mouseover element ?

Comment: Which child? the answer can't be answered in the current form.

Comment: sorry guys..i'll edit the question.

Comment: @GihanDilusha, people still waiting for your HTML code I guess. Its very difficult to assume where is what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the event `.stopPropagation()` method in the event handler function.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').mouseenter(function(event){
        var id = $(this).siblings('.tooltip-c').attr('id');
        $('.tp'+id).fadeIn(500);
        event.stopPropagation(); 
     });
});
```

Comment: @Gihan Dilusha in your event handler function parameter pass `e` or `event` and then use `.stopPropagation` as its method.

Comment: i used even. but it is same :(

Answer (score 20):

Try using [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead. They handle event bubbling differently from `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()`. I think it should solve your problem:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').mouseenter(function(e){
    var id = $(this).siblings('.tooltip-c').attr('id');
    $('.tp'+id).fadeIn(500);
    $('.tp'+id ).mouseleave(function(event){
      $('.tp'+id).fadeOut(300);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This solved my problem straight-away, I couldn't get the other solutions to work for me.

Comment: Works better than all mouseover/mouseout solutions, and all event prevent default. Works ok on IE11 and Chrome.